# GNU emacs lisp: string match (how to pass emacs-version correctly)

Tags: functions, variables

I'm newbie with Emacs and I'm experimenting with Lisp on GNU Emacs-26.1. Can't understand why the following simple piece of Elisp code does not work:

```lisp
    (string-match "^GNU Emacs" emacs-version)
```

If I just leave as

```lisp
    (string-match "Emacs" emacs-version)
```

it still returns `nil`

However,

```lisp
    (string-match "^GNU Emacs" "GNU Emacs 26.1")
```

returns `0 (#o0, #x0, ?\C-@)` i.e. position 0 as expected.

It always return `nil`, although `M-x emacs version` returns:

```
GNU Emacs 26.1 (build 1. x86-64-redhat-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version 3.22.30) of 2021-08-05
```

How to get `emacs-version` to evaluate to a string such as `"GNU Emacs 26.1..."`?

Comment: emacs.stackexchange.com/tags/elisp/info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code uses `emacs-version` as a variable, not as a function.

*Variable* `emacs-version` returns a string such as this: `"26.1"`. *Function* `emacs-version` returns a string such as this: `"GNU Emacs 26.1 (build 1. x86-64-redhat-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version 3.22.30) of 2021-08-05"`.

To invoke the function instead of evaluating the variable, use `(emacs-version)` instead of `emacs-version`.

When you use `M-x emacs-version` you invoke the *command*, that is, the *function*, `emacs-version` (a command is a function that can be invoked interactively -- with `M-x` or with a key bound to it).